# Duplicidad de datos en un GRIDVIEW (en la base de datos son registros únicos)

Tags: android-studio, sqlite, gridview

Llevo unos días teniendo un problema con la recuperación de datos de una base de datos local con SQLite en Android Studio.
En la base de datos, si tengo 2 registros, el gridview donde los represento, me crea 4 item, vamos que los repite.

Un ejemplo de como me lo muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Consulto a la base de datos el numero de registros, me los da correctos, los cargo a un ArrayList, al que pregunto cuantos hay, y también me devuelve el dato correcto.
Por tanto creo que no es problema del adaptador aunque os dejo el codigo

```
//CONSTRUCTOR
public AdaptadorListView(Context context, int layout, List<Obra> obras) {
    super(context, layout, obras);
    this.layout = layout;
    this.obras = obras;
}

//GENERA LA VISTA
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int posicion, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup padre) {
    View vista = LayoutInflater.from(padre.getContext()).inflate(layout, null, true);
    //REFERENCIAMOS LOS ELEMENTOS DE UI
    TextView tvCodigo = vista.findViewById(R.id.tvCodigoItem);
    TextView tvAgnoItem = vista.findViewById(R.id.tvAgnoItem);
    TextView tvTituloItem = vista.findViewById(R.id.tvTituloItem);
    TextView tvMedidasItem = vista.findViewById(R.id.tvMedidasItem);
    //MODIFICAMOS LOS TEXTOS POR LOS VALORES RECIBIDOS DE LA BBDD
    tvCodigo.setText(obras.get(posicion).getCodigoObra());
    String agno = obras.get(posicion).getAgnoObra() + "";
    tvAgnoItem.setText(agno);
    tvTituloItem.setText(obras.get(posicion).getTituloObra());
    String medidas = obras.get(posicion).getAltoObra() + " x " + obras.get(posicion).getAnchoObra();
    tvMedidasItem.setText(medidas);
    try {
        if (obras.get(posicion).getUbicacionObra().length() < 2) {
            tvCodigo.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            tvAgnoItem.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            tvTituloItem.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            tvMedidasItem.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        }
    } catch (Exception ignorated){
        tvCodigo.setPaintFlags(0);
        tvAgnoItem.setPaintFlags(0);
        tvTituloItem.setPaintFlags(0);
        tvMedidasItem.setPaintFlags(0);
    }

    //CARGAMOS LA IMAGEN
    final String codigo = tvCodigo.getText().toString();
    final ImageView ivFotoGrid = vista.findViewById(R.id.ivFotoItem);
    final ProgressBar pb = vista.findViewById(R.id.pbItem);
    Util.muestraFoto(codigo, ivFotoGrid, pb);

    //DEVOLVEMOS LA VISTA
    return vista;
}
```

Creo que tampoco es problema del Fragmento donde tengo el gridview pero os lo dejo....

```
public class FavoritosGridFragment extends Fragment {
//CREACIÓN DE LOS OBJETOS DE CLASE
private FragmentFavoritosGridBinding binding;
//CREACIÓN DE LOS OBJETOS DE CLASE NECESARIOS PARA CREAR Y RELLENAR EL LISTVIEW
public static AdaptadorListView adaptadorFav;
private int posicionFav = 0;
public static final ArrayList<Obra> favoritos = new ArrayList<>();

//CONSTRUCTOR VACIO NECESARIO PARA EL FRAGMENT
public FavoritosGridFragment() {

}

//~~~~ CICLOS DE VIDA ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = FragmentFavoritosGridBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View vistaFavFrag = binding.getRoot();
    //~~~~~~~~ LÓGICA DEL FRAGMENTO ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Util.numFragmento = Util.FAV;
    Util.viendo = Util.VIENDO_FAV;
    //AÑADIMOS ESTE FRAGMENTO EN LA VARIABLE PARA RECUPERARLO EN ONRESUME
    if (MainActivity.oldFragmento[0] != Util.FAV) Util.historial(false, Util.FAV);

    //PREPARAMOS EL LISTVIEW CON SU ADAPTADOR Y EL ARRAY DONDE ALMACENAMOS LOS FAVORITOS
    favoritos.clear();
    adaptadorFav = new AdaptadorListView(getContext(), R.layout.item_obra, favoritos);
    binding.gvFavoritos.setAdapter(adaptadorFav);
    //COMPROBAMOS EL DISPOSTIVO PARA CONFIGURAR EL NUMERO DE COLUMNAS
    if (Util.esTabletH(requireContext())) binding.gvFavoritos.setNumColumns(5);
    else if (Util.esTablet(requireContext())) binding.gvFavoritos.setNumColumns(3);
    else binding.gvFavoritos.setNumColumns(2);

    //**********************************************************************************
    //****LAS ÓRDENES RELATIVAS A LA VISUALIZACIÓN DE LOS FAVORITOS SE MUEVEN***********
    //**** AL MÉTODO ONRESUME EVITANDO ASI LA DUPLICIDAD DE DATOS QUE GENERABA**********
    //**********************************************************************************


    if (Util.venimosFicha) {
        //POSICIONAMOS LOS DATOS SEGÚN SI ES LA PRIMERA VEZ DE LA BUSQUEDA O VOLVEMOS DE OTRO SITIO
        binding.gvFavoritos.setSelection(Util.posicionClicada);
        adaptadorFav.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //TODO: SI TUVIERAMOS, DEBERIAMOS QUITAR EL PROGRESSBAR
        /*
        //LLAMAMOS AL HELPER QUE NOS CREA LA BBDD
        adaptadorFav = new AdaptadorListView(getContext(), R.layout.item_obra, todasMisFavoritas());
        binding.gvFavoritos.setAdapter(adaptadorFav);*/
    } else {
        favoritos.clear();
    }
    actualizarBD();

    return vistaFavFrag;
}

//~~~~ UNA VEZ CREADA LA VISTA PONEMOS LOS BOTONES A LA ESCUCHA ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //~~~~ PONEMOS LOS ITEM DEL LISTVIEW A LA ESCUCHA ~~~~
    binding.gvFavoritos.setOnItemClickListener((parent, v, position, id) -> {
        //RECOGEMOS EL CÓDIGO DE LA OBRA CLICKADA
        String obraClickada = favoritos.get(position).getCodigoObra();
        requireActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.contenido_fragment, new FichaFragment(obraClickada))
                .commit();
    });
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
}

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//~~~~ MÉTODOS PROPIOS ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//MÉTODO QUE ACTUALIZA LOS FAVORITOS
private void actualizarBD() {
    todasMisFavoritas();
    //BORRAMOS EL LISTADO, RECOGEMOS TODAS LAS OBRAS Y REFRESCAMOS EL ADAPTADOR
    favoritos.addAll(favoritos);
    //SI NO HAY FAVORITOS QUE MOSTRAR
    if (favoritos.size() == 0) {
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder sinFavoritos = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getContext());
        sinFavoritos
                .setTitle(R.string.TitFavoritos)
                .setMessage(R.string.menSinFav)
                .setNeutralButton(R.string.BoAceptar, (dialog, which) -> {
                    Util.historial(true, Util.EXIT);
                    requireActivity()
                            .getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.contenido_fragment,
                                    Util.recuperaFragmento(MainActivity.oldFragmento[0]))
                            .commit();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                })
                .create()
                .show();
    }
}

//MÉTODO QUE RECOGE TODOS LOS FAVORITOS DE LA BD
private void todasMisFavoritas() {
    favoritos.clear();

    //CREAMOS EL ITERADOR DE LA BD
    SQLiteDatabase dbR = MainActivity.helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbR.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + FavoritosHelper.DB_TABLA + " ORDER BY CODIGO, ANO", null);

    //TODO: SOLO COMO COMPROBACION
    int i = cursor.getCount();
    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "En el cursor hay " + i + " elementos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //RECORREMOS LA BD CON EL CURSOR, ALIMENTANDO LA LISTA
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Obra obra = new Obra();
            obra.setCodigoObra(cursor.getString(0));
            obra.setTituloObra(cursor.getString(1));
            obra.setAgnoObra(cursor.getInt(2));
            obra.setAltoObra(cursor.getInt(3));
            obra.setAnchoObra(cursor.getInt(4));
            obra.setUbicacionObra(cursor.getString(5));
            favoritos.add(obra);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Alguna idea de donde puede estar el error????

Comment: Problema solucionado, soy tan tonto que estaba sumando la lista de respuestas a la lista de respuestas.....    favoritos.addAll(favoritos);  Mira que no darme cuenta de eso....    Se puede cerrar el hilo......

Comment: *Se puede cerrar el hilo* -> Esto no es un foro... es un lugar de preguntas/respuestas. Una pregunta sin respuesta no debería ser cerrada sin más. Pon tu comentario como respuesta, aquí abajo hay un gran espacio donde pone "Tu Respuesta" y hay una caja para "responder", escribe ahí tu respuesta y **luego la aceptas**, eso es lo que "cierra" el hilo. No podemos cerrar una pregunta que has hecho tú, tú eres el autor, tú eres el que debe gestionar la pregunta. Y si era por un error y no quieres "publicar" una respuesta, siempre puedes borrarla, cualquier cosa menos dejarla abierta por favor.